# ERROR : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm and wanted to install pandas in my project.
So, I used the following commands(one by one because the first one didn't work) in the terminal of PyCharm to do it.

```
>pip install pandas
>python -m pip install pandas
```

I got the same errors for both of them. 
ERROR :

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pandas
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not a
vailable.")': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not a
vailable.")': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not a
vailable.")': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not a
vailable.")': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not a
vailable.")': /simple/pandas/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded w
ith url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with u
rl: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

How do I install pandas now? Please help.

OS : Windows 10 
Python version : Python 3.7.6 
pip version : pip 19.0.3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, my system has Anaconda installed and while creating the project, I forgot to the change the 'basic interpreter' from Conda to normal python.exe, that's why I wasn't able to install anything in it as I was using Anaconda's pip.

Comment: Why not use Conda for the project?